# How many Legal positions of tic tac toe are possible? (Ignoring symmetry)

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-game-theory, tic-tac-toe

**I wanted to know how many possible legal positions of tic-tac-toe can be found if we ignore symmetry. I have done a little calculation myself but the answers i have found in the internet are way larger than mine. Can someone please check if my calculations are correct?**

## My Answer:

For move $1$ , There are 9 squares to place 1 object; (O or X doesn't matter)
So , Total positions = $9$

For move $2$, There are 9 squares to place 2 objects;
So, Total positions= $^9P_2 = 72$

For move $3$, We have to place 3 objects in 9 squares, but 2 of them are same;
So, Total Positions=$\frac{^9P_3}{2!}= 252$

For move $4$, It will be 4 objects but of 2 types;
So, Total positions= $\frac{^9P_4}{2!2!}= 756$

In this method we can work out the rest as well:

Move $5= \frac{^9P_5}{3!2!}= 1260$

Move $6= \frac{^9P_6}{3!3!}= 1680$

Move $7= \frac{^9P_7}{4!3!}= 1260$

Move $8= \frac{^9P_8}{4!4!}= 1630$

Move $9= \frac{^9P_9}{5!4!}= 126$

In total, $$\sum_{i=1}^{n=9} \frac{^nP_i}{\left\lfloor\frac{i}{2}\right\rfloor!\left\lceil\frac{i}{2}\right\rceil!} = (9+72+252+756+1260+1680+1260+1630+126) = 6045$$

**Is my answer correct? Is there anything wrong in my calculations? I came up with the equation for the sum by looking at the trend of the positions in each move. Is the equation correct?**

Comment: Clarify... are you looking for legal final game states where all that matters is the position of the naughts and crosses at the end after the game has concluded?  Are you looking where the game does not need to have concluded yet?  Are you looking for legal final game **histories** where not only do we care about where each naught or cross ended up at but we also care about the order in which each was placed?  Are you taking into account the "*legal*" clause of what you are looking to count and avoiding impossible scenarios such as where both players have threes in a row?

Comment: What answers *have* you found on the internet?  You say they were larger than yours, but by how much.  Did the sources of those other numbers share any information as to how they calculated them or what interpretations of the problem they were using that might vary from yours?

Comment: Under the assumption that you are simply trying to enumerate the number of different ways that $9$ cells can be partitioned into two subsets, one of which has $5$ cells, the other has $4$ cells, then the enumeration is $~\displaystyle \binom{9}{5} = 126.~$  I am assuming that the order that the cells are added to each subset is irrelevant.

Comment: @JMoravitz I only wanted every legal position during Any moment in the game. The game doesn't necessarily have to finish.

Comment: That only answered a very small portion of what I had asked.  Game *states* or game *histories*?  Are the numbers you cite having found which were larger than yours about states or about histories?  Are you caring whether or not a game is actually *legal* in that the game could have continued to such a point without having been ended early?  For instance, $\begin{array}{c|c|c}X&&O\\ \hline X&&O\\\hline X&&O\end{array}$ is impossible because after the fifth symbol was placed the game ended immediately as a win for the first player

Comment: @JMoravitz The order doesn't matter . But yes i failed to take that impossible position into account that you mentioned

Comment: *Are the numbers you cite having found which were larger than yours about states or about histories?  Who, what, where, and how did this numbers come about?*  Third time I've asked this question now.

Comment: there are these 2 I found: https://www.quora.com/How-many-possible-tic-tac-toe-games-are-there    https://www.reddit.com/r/theydidthemath/comments/n91rb5/request_how_many_legal_tic_tac_toe_boards_are/

Comment: The punchline is that your answer you found seems reasonable and correct if we were to go with the interpretation you have with regards to whether we are counting game states vs game histories (you are counting game states to not include the history of the order in which moves were made), where the first player always starts with X, and where we ignore the impossibility/illegality of certain positions which should have ended prematurely, we ignore the empty board state, and allow incomplete games.  Your answer is if anything *too large* for your interpretation.

Comment: @JMoravitz Understood. I will have to try to solve the impossible position problem